# Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, joomla-framework-1.x

I have hosted web application develop using joomla in ubuntu 20 and use mysql as database.
one i hosted and viewed in the web browser it show me **Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session**

i have used php 7.4, mysql Ver 8.0.27, apache Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support. We are likely to need more details. Is this a new build? If not, what has recently changed? You may [edit] your question whenever and as often as you like.  Is this question different from your previous question?

Answer (score 2):

Joomla works with sessions. It needs to be able to write session info to the #__session table in the database. Your error message indicates that Joomla cannot write to the database, hence it cannot start its session.

Could you double check your MySQL credentials with the credentials in your configuration.php?

```
 public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
 public $host = 'localhost';
 public $user = 'some-user';
 public $password = 'some-secret-password';
 public $db = 'the-name-of-your-database';
 public $dbprefix = 'the-table-prefix_';
```

Comment: I have check by using mysql -u {name} -p command by using the values in the configuration.php file and it work and log into mysql database.

Comment: Ok, something else to check: can PHP access your MySQL database. Do you have the PHP module ```php-mysql``` installed on the server? Could you use the https://forumpostassistant.github.io/docs/ to analyze your website / server environment?

Answer (score 1):

1. Common causes for the “failed to start session” error in Joomla:  see https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=982009
2. Make sure that your version of PHP can connect to the database:  see [Optional Technical Requirements for J! 3.x](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Optional_Technical_Requirements)

3. Unusual causes for this error:
   (a) Tinkering with the file **configuration.php** to change the SQL user password; or
   (b) Is your disk full?